# Use prometheus metrics servlet in management port of springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, prometheus

I'm using prometheus metric servlet to expose my metrics, with the java client api prometheus supply.

I registered the servlet the same way of registering any servelt, see below:

```
 @Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean registerPrometheusExporterServlet(CollectorRegistry metricRegistry) {
    return new ServletRegistrationBean(new MetricsServlet(metricRegistry), "/metrics");
}
```

However, I would like to add this servlet to the management port or if it is possible that the prometheus version will replace the default /metrics service of springboot.
Can something like this can be done? and how?

Thanks,
Daniela

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if you were able to integrate Spring Boot with Prometheus, but now there is a dedicated connector in the official Prometheus `client-java` project.

The Github page of the project is the following: [simpleclient_spring_boot](https://github.com/prometheus/client_java/tree/master/simpleclient_spring_boot)

You can use it adding the following dependency to you `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.prometheus</groupId>
    <artifactId>simpleclient_spring_boot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.17</version>
</dependency>
```

To use it, add a Spring Boot configuration to your project, like the following.

```
@Configuration
public class MetricsConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean() {
        DefaultExports.initialize();
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(new MetricsServlet(), "/prometheus");
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringBootMetricsCollector springBootMetricsCollector(Collection<PublicMetrics> publicMetrics) {
        SpringBootMetricsCollector springBootMetricsCollector = new SpringBootMetricsCollector(
            publicMetrics);
        springBootMetricsCollector.register();
        return springBootMetricsCollector;
    }
}
```

Now on, the metrics exposed by Spring Boot Actuator will be available as Prometheus Counters and Gauges.

The information are published to the path `/prometheus` of your application. Then you have to instruct Prometheus to consume this information, with a configuration like the following.

```
# my global config
global:
  scrape_interval:     15s # By default, scrape targets every 15 seconds.
  evaluation_interval: 15s # By default, scrape targets every 15 seconds.

# A scrape configuration containing exactly one endpoint to scrape:
# Here it's Prometheus itself.
scrape_configs:
- job_name: 'your-application-name'

  scrape_interval: 5s

  metrics_path: '/prometheus'

  static_configs:
    - targets: ['localhost:8080']
```

If you point your browser to `/metrics` you will continue to see information in Spring Boot format. But, pointing the browser to `http://localhost:9090/graph` you will query into such information directly into Prometheus query browser.

Try to have a look also to [this](https://github.com/prometheus/client_java/pull/114) Github pull-request.

**UPDATE**

In the next release of the `simpleclient_spring_boot`, 0.0.18, it will be sufficient to add the annotation `@EnablePrometheusEndpoint` to the configuration class of Spring Boot to *automagically* configure the Prometheus adapter (have a look to this [test](https://github.com/prometheus/client_java/blob/master/simpleclient_spring_boot/src/test/java/io/prometheus/client/spring/boot/PrometheusEndpointTest.java))!

Hope it helps.

Comment: I did this and it works, but in one workspace i am getting this The constructor ServletRegistrationBean(MetricsServlet, String) is undefined and i dont know how to solve ti. What can cause this?

Comment: Forget the configuration class. Enable Prometheus directly from Boot, using the annotation `@EnablePrometheusEndpoint` in your application :)

Comment: Thank you for fast response. I did this and now on which route to see the metrics?

Comment: With the config i can set the metrics servlet and url ( /prometheus) and i can see the metrics there.

With this Annotation where to see the metrics. I am accessing /prometheus and i am getting: Not found

Comment: Sorry, but it has passed a lot of time. Do you see something under `/metrics`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167620/discussion-between-bambus-and-riccardo-cardin).

Comment: Hi, how is the process on Spring 5 (Springboot 2.1.5)? @EnablePrometheusEndpoint annotation gives an error.

Comment: **PublicMetrics** is not available from `spring boot 2`, how can I implement springBootMetricsCollector for spring boot 2? I tried `@EnableSpringBootMetricsCollector` getting exception `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.PublicMetrics`